# Precompile script into objects inside C++ application

Tags: c++, scripting, compilation

I need to provide my users the ability to write mathematical computations into the program. I plan to have a simple text interface with a few buttons including those to validate the script grammar, save etc.

Here's where it gets interesting. These functions the user is writing need to execute at multi-megabyte line speeds in a communications application. So I need the speed of a compiled language, but the usage of a script. A fully interpreted language just won't cut it.

My idea is to precompile the saved user modules into objects at initialization of the C++ application. I could then use these objects to execute the code when called upon. Here are the workflows I have in mind:

1) Testing(initial writing) of script: Write code in editor, save, compile into object (testing grammar), run with test I/O, Edit Code

2) Use of Code (Normal operation of application): Load script from file, compile script into object, Run object code, Run object code, Run object code, etc.

I've looked into several off the shelf interpreters, but can't find what I'm looking for. I considered JAVA, as it is pretty fast, but I would need to load the JAVA virtual machine, which means passing objects between C and the virtual machine... The interface is the bottleneck here. I really need to create a native C++ object running C++ code if possible. I also need to be able to run the code on multiple processors effectively in a controlled manner.

I'm not looking for the whole explanation on how to pull this off, as I can do my own research. I've been stalled for a couple days here now, however, and I really need a place to start looking.

As a last resort, I will create my own scripting language to fulfill the need, but that seems a waste with all the great interpreters out there. I've also considered taking an existing open source complier and slicing it up for the functionality I need... just not saving the compiled results to disk... I don't know. I would prefer to use a mainline language if possible... but that's not required.

Any help would be appreciated. I know this is not your run of the mill idea I have here, but someone has to have done it before.

Thanks!

P.S.
One thought that just occurred to me while writing this was this: what about using a true C compiler to create object code, save it to disk as a dll library, then reload and run it inside "my" code? Can you do that with MS Visual Studio? I need to look at the licensing of the compiler... how to reload the library dynamically while the main application continues to run... hmmmmm I could then just group the "functions" created by the user into library groups. Ok that's enough of this particular brain dump...

Comment: What about JavaScript? There few embeddable engines available(including JIT).

Comment: I think this question is a bit too broad, like "I'd like to write a game engine (or whatever). What should I do?" Please state your specific programming problem. Create an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for it.

Comment: ibre, could you extend your comment somewhat? I tried looking into JavaScript, but I did not find an embeddable JIT... Could you give me a specific starting place? (ie address?) THANKS!

Comment: Tobi, at it's essence, I need a programming language of some form that I can recompile and run on the fly while the larger program is executing. To this end, I am asking for starting points for further research and maybe a few pointers along the way (ie examples of similar solutions, lessons learned from previous attempts etc.)

Comment: even Mozilla's SpiderMonkey used to be separate project before it become part of the browser. Also QT framework offers Webkit and JSript as embedable DDLs.

Comment: See QtStript here http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtscript-index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution could be use gcc (MingW since you are on windows) and build a DLL out of your user defined code. The DLL should export just one function. You can use the win32 API to handle the DLL (LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress etc.) At the end of this job you have a C style function pointer. The problem now are arguments. If your computation has just one parameter you can fo a cast to `double (*funct)(double)`, but if you have many parameters you need to match them.

Comment: I plan to standardize the interface for all user defined functions, basically wrapping them into my code. This would take care of the interfacing problems you described.

Comment: This may have given me a glimmer of a starting point. If I dynamically load these libraries, and group the functions at large into consistent sub catagories, I may be able to recompile functions on the fly in native C code. The problem I might hit up against would be that I am using Visual C++, and I have no idea what the licensing requirements for this type of usage might be.... maybe the free version of the compiler?

Comment: I clicked accept on the answer because it gave me the starting point I needed. Thanks for the help! Just need to see now if I can make it work lol.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a way to do this using standard C.

1) Standard C needs to be used because when it is compiled into a dll, the resulting interface is cross compatible with multiple compilers. I plan to do my primary development with MS Visual Studio and compile objects in my application using gcc (windows version)

2) I will expose certain variables to the user (inputs and outputs) and standardize them across units. This allows multiple units to be developed with the same interface.

3) The user will only create the inside of the function using standard C syntax and grammar. I will then wrap that function with text to fully define the function and it's environment (remember those variables I intend to expose?) I can also group multiple functions under a single executable unit (dll) using name parameters.

4) When the user wishes to test their function, I dump the dll from memory, compile their code with my wrappers in gcc, and then reload the dll into memory and run it. I would let them define inputs and outputs for testing.

5) Once the test/create step was complete, I have a compiled library created which can be loaded at run time and handled via pointers. The inputs and outputs would be standardized, so I would always know what my I/O was.

6) The only problem with standardized I/O is that some of the inputs and outputs are likely to not be used. I need to see if I can put default values in or something.

So, to sum up:

Think of an app with a text box and a few buttons. You are told that your inputs are named A, B, and C and that your outputs are X, Y, and Z of specified types. You then write a function using standard C code, and with functions from the specified libraries (I'm thinking math etc.)

So now your done... you see a few boxes below to define your input. You fill them in and hit the TEST button. This would wrap your code in a function context, dump the existing dll from memory (if it exists) and compile your code along with any other functions in the same group (another parameter you could define, basically just a name to the user.) It then runs the function using a functional pointer, using the inputs defined in the UI. The outputs are sent to the user so they can determine if their function works. If there are any compilation errors, that would also be outputted to the user.

Now it's time to run for real. Of course I kept track of what functions are where, so I dynamically open the dll, and load all the functions into memory with functional pointers. I start shoving data into one side and the functions give me the answers I need. There would be some overhead to track I/O and to make sure the functions are called in the right order, but the execution would be at compiled machine code speeds... which is my primary requirement.

Now... I have explained what I think will work in two different ways. Can you think of anything that would keep this from working, or perhaps any advice/gotchas/lessons learned that would help me out? Anything from the type of interface to tips on dynamically loading dll's in this manner to using the gcc compiler this way... etc would be most helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: A nice to have would be the possibility to show any compile error to the user, at least to an advanced one. Otherwise it's difficult to fix just simple typos...

Comment: yes... that and status information on what's going on. It might take some time to compile if someone gets fancy with their functions, or if there are a large number in the same batch under the same group name.